# Why is the synchronized method not getting locked unless I use .join()?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

In `Java`, marking a method `synchronized` should disable the  **race condition**  that would result from two threads calling the method which is accessing and modifying a field in the same object.

But for some reason, `synchronized` is not working as expected in the following example unless I call `.join()` on both threads in the main program. Why is that?

```
package example;

public class Account {
    private double balance;

    public Account(double balance) {
        super();
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

```
package example;

public class AccountTester extends Thread {
    private Account account;
    private double amount;

    public AccountTester(Account account, double amount) {
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(0);
        AccountTester tester1 = new AccountTester(account, 1.0);
        AccountTester tester2 = new AccountTester(account, 2.0);
        tester1.start();
        tester2.start();
        // Why do I need the main thread to join threads
        //      tester1 and tester2 for synchronized to work?
        try {
            tester1.join();
            tester2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("End balance: " + account.getBalance());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            account.deposit(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `synchronized` method. If you don't `join` the program will exit without waiting for the threads to actually do any work. Starting a thread is not instant, try a `sleep(1000)` instead of a `join` and see the difference.

Comment: Thank you @flakes. This was very helpful for my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by @flakes, the code needed the main thread to `join()` both threads to guarantee that both threads are terminated, i.e. done with their modification to the balance, before it printed out the end `balance`.

A cleaner way to implement this would be by using the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` interface. Here its `shutdown()` method guarantees that both threads in the *thread pool* are completed before printing the end `balance`. Here's my implementation:

```
package example;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class AccountTester implements Runnable {
    private Account account;
    private double amount;

    public AccountTester(Account account, double amount) {
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(0);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(new AccountTester(account, 1.0));
        executorService.execute(new AccountTester(account, 2.0));
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("End balance: " + account.getBalance());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            account.deposit(amount);
        }
    }
}
```